# Xcode project files missing - but still defined in project

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks

I have an Xcode project where I imported an outside framework (Theo) to bridge Swift into a Neo4j server.

My code still works, but the files related to the framework no longer shows up in my project manager.  I even wrote some custom code into one of the framework models, which I am able to access in my other code areas even though I can no longer find that original code.

I checked to make sure I hadn't filtered out sections in the project manager, which I haven't.

In my visible code, if I use code from the framework model, I can "search definition" and it jumps me to a definition page with info from that framework, but I still cannot access the entire code.

Any thoughts?  I need help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Theo has just been updated to version 3.0, and now includes instructions on how to integrate it in your project either as a git submodule, CococaPod, with Carthage, or through the Swift Package Manager. Check it out. Personally, I really like CocoaPods for iOS projects.